# How do I display pandas column blurry?

Tags: python, pandas, printing, data-visualization, display

I have a pandas dataframe that I would like to display. Some of my columns contain personal data. Is it possible to show a column and make its values appear blurry? Consider this example dataframe:

```
# initialize list of lists 
data = [['tom', 10, 'New York'], ['nick', 15., 'London' ], ['juli', 14, 'Berlin']] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Hometown']) 

# print dataframe. 
df
```

Desired output:
Pandas dataframe is printed / displayed completely including column names. Age column values are blurry and not readable. My column does not contain image data, but here an example with what I mean when I say blurry:

[image]

Comment: Did you have a look at pandas styling? You could imagine filling the personal data cells with black background https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html ?

Comment: Hey @Arnaud thanks for the suggestion. I know the style page and think it is helpful. However I would like to image fill my column only as a last resort.

Comment: Using pandas styling does not make you fill cells with images (although it could), it's actually modifying the HTML/CSS behind your printed dataframe. You could apply a particular blurry CSS (playing with `color` and `text-shadow` attributes for instance) to your sensitive columns. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working way to do that blurring:

```
def blurry(s):
    return 'color: transparent; text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'

df.style.applymap(blurry, subset=["Age"])
```

And the result is:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. You can play further with `text-shadow` to make things more or less blurry. One caveat is of course that when selecting the text, it becomes visible again: the data is still there. But as an illustration, it works!